# Interpreting $\sum_a^b$ when $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, summation, complex-integration, discrete-calculus

I'm doing a problem that involves

$$\sum_{k=ad}^{bd}d^{-1}f(kd^{-1})$$

where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. You might recognise this as a special case of the numerical integration formula, which is related to the problem. However, the main issue is that I need to define what happens when $a, b \in \Bbb{C}$.

Google won't help me, and I can't find similar questions.

So, how would I compute $\sum_a^b\{a, b \in C\}$?

I don't mean abstractly, as most other people on this forum (who are far smarter than me) would ask, I mean literally for two values $a$ and $b$.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: This is not defined because the complex numbers are not an ordered set, so $\sum_a^b$ has no meaning when $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$. When they are real numbers, the meaning is that you sum over all values that lie between $a$ and $b$. But there's no such ordering on the set of complex numbers.

Comment: @QuaereVerum I think that deserves to be an answer. And to the downvoters — do not use downvote to express a "no" answer, because that's not what votes are for, that's what answers are for!

Comment: Do you mean $d^{-1}f(kd^{-1})?$ Because $x$ is a constant as written.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for catching that! Typo.

Comment: @QuaereVerum If it's undefined, how is it that the limit as $d\to 0$ defines the integral, which is more continuous and yet is defined over the complex numbers?

Comment: What definition of complex integration are you looking at exactly? I feel like your problem can be easily resolved by actually studying the correct definition

Comment: Maybe there's some appropriate definition of "contour summation"?

Comment: Contour integrals are most easily defined as Riemann integrals of the real and imaginary parts of a suitable function. Then you can use ordinary summation notation to help you

Comment: Maybe your understanding that your original problem "involves" what you say it does is wrong. This could be an [XY issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Lorago I'm aware there are ways to turn it into $\sum_{k=a_1}^{b_1}f(k)+i\sum_{k=a_2}^{b_2}g(k)$, I just mean in a more theoretical sense.

Comment: @coiso I care about this beyond the original problem in which I discovered it.

Comment: @FShrike I've used this to solve the original problem, but there are many situations where knowing the sum from $C \to C$ is useful.

Comment: @SigMoid I have never seen any such situation. Summation can always be taken over integers, regardless of what the quantities are that you’re summing

Comment: Still, the original problem in which you encountered it may shine light on how to interpret the sum.

Comment: @coiso I was trying to create a software that implemented numerical integration, and came across a situation involving complex numbers. I skipped past it with some roundabout programming, but the complex case of a sum is still an incredibly important concept, especially when contrasted as a discreet alternative to a complex integral expression.

Comment: I think the elephant in the room is how you're defining $\sum_{k=ad}^{bd}d^{-1}f(kd^{-1})$. What is $d^{-1}$ and what is $f$?

Comment: @Accelerator $d$ is a constant, $d^{-1}$ is a unary operation on $d$, and $f(x)$ is an arbitrary function $R \to R$

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes $\sum_{k=a}^b f(k)$, where $a\le b$ integers, has a closed form which obviously extends to complex numbers.  Use that closed form.  But in most cases, there is no such thing.

Example
$$
\sum_{k=a}^b k^2 = \frac{2b^3+3b^2+b-2a^3+3a^2-a}{6}
$$

Comment: I mean in general, how would one compute the sum from complex to complex?

Answer (score 0):

For sufficiently nice functions $f$, you can use the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula):

$$ \sum_{a<k\le b}f(k)=\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_{k+1}}{(k+1)!} \Big(f^{(k)}(b)-f^{(k)}(a)\Big). $$

Here, $B_s$ are the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) with $B_1=+\frac{1}{2}$ and $B_s=0$ for all odd $s>1$. How you want to finagle the $a<k\le b$ condition to plug complex numbers in I'll leave up to you.

"Nice" means not too oscillatory: $\int_a^b|f^{(k)}(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x=o\big((2\pi)^k\big)$ for all $a,b$ should do the trick.

Comment: I guess $||a|| \< ||k|| \{<=} ||b||$ works okay. I'll need to find a function for the Bernoulli numbers, but this should typically work. In this context, what do you mean by o(x)? I typically hear about it in terms of operations, so I'm not sure what it means in this context.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation